# Central Difference to Approximate f'(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

So, Let $f(x) = \frac{1} {1 + x^2}$, $f'(x) = Af(x-2h) + Bf(x-h) + Cf(x) + Df(x+h) + Ef(x+2h)$, Use central difference scheme to approximate $f'(1)$ to show the order of convergence and the de-stabilization of the numerical methods of $h$.

So using central difference formula i've gotten this far, but im stuck as what to do next:

$f(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{1+(1+h)^2} - \frac{1}{1+(x-h)^2}}{2h}$

$f'(x) = \frac{\frac{2(x+h)}{((x+h)^2+1)^2} - \frac{2(x-h)}{((x-h)^2+1)^2}}{2h}$

do i plug in 1 for x? What do i have to do or use with the other equation? My notes on the matter just show scientific notation.

::::EDIT::::

I decided to take another approach, i expanded the taylor series and multiplied by $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. So i get something link this: $ \frac{f(x)}{2h+2hx^2} + \frac{f'(x)}{2h+2hx^2} + \frac{f''(x)}{4h+4hx^2} + \frac{f'''(x)h^2}{6h + 6hx^2} - \frac{f'(x)}{2h+2hx^2} + \frac{f''(x)}{4h+4hx^2}-\frac{f'''(x)h^2}{6h + 6hx^2} $ Then we remove like terms and simplify: $ \frac{f'(x)}{h + hx^2} + \frac{f'''(x)h^2}{3h + 4hx^2} + \frac{f''''(x)h^4}{5h + 5hx^2} $ somehow $\frac{f'''(x)h^2}{3h + 3hx^2}$ is chosen to be $\frac{f(c)h^2}{3h+3hx^2}$ and is rewritten as $theta(h^2)$ and this makes it the central difference a scheme of order two.

Comment: I decided to take another approach:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the overall idea without completely solving your homework, change to the second derivative and another function.

I take it that the approximation formula has to make the best of all 5 function values. At first, forget about the specific form of $f$, only use that it is sufficiently often continuously differentiable. Then by combining Taylor series the normal central difference formula has error terms
$$
D_2(x,h)=\frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2}=f''(x)+\frac{2f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}h^2+\frac{2f^{(6)}(x)}{6!}h^4+\frac{2f^{(8)}(x)}{8!}h^6+...
$$
Now replace $h$ by $2h$ in that formula$$
D_2(x,2h)=\frac{f(x-2h)-2f(x)+f(x+2h)}{4h^2}=f''(x)+\frac{2\cdot 2^2f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}h^2+\frac{2⋅2^4f^{(6)}(x)}{6!}h^4+\frac{2⋅2^6f^{(8)}(x)}{8!}h^6+...
$$
Now it is easy to see what combination of both formulas will eliminate the leading quadratic error term
$$
4D_2(x,h)-D_2(x,2h)=3f''(x)-\frac{2⋅(2^4-4)f^{(6)}(x)}{6!}h^4+O(h^6)
$$
giving the formula
\begin{align}
D_4(x,h)=\frac{4D_2(x,h)-D_2(x,2h)}3
&=\frac{-f(x-2h)+16f(x-h)-30f(x)+16f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{12h^2}\\
&=f''(x)-\frac{f^{(6)}(x)}{90}h^4+O(h^6)
\end{align}

For $f(x)=\sin(x)$ where we know $f''(x)=-\sin(x)=f^{(6)}(x)$, we can try to numerically confirm that picture

[image]

where the error is drawn together with the numerical error bound composed of bounds for the floating point evaluation and the leading error term
$$
\frac{64|f(x)|\epsilon}{12h^2}+\frac{|f^{(6)}(x)|}{90}h^4
$$
where $ϵ\simeq 10^{-16}$ is the floating point machine constant.
As to be expected from this formula, the error is minimal where the terms are equal, around $h\sim\sqrt[6]{500ϵ}\approx 0.006$.

Comment: wow, okay, i somewhat get it, but what about these two equations that were provided, what purpose do they serve? : $f(x) = \frac{1} {1 + x^2}$, $f'(x) = Af(x-2h) + Bf(x-h) + Cf(x) + Df(x+h) + Ef(x+2h)$

Comment: You have to determine these numbers $A,B,C,D,E$. They are universal constant relative to $f$ and should be scalar multiples of $1/h$.